# TronWeb UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, solidity

I'm triyng build interfacing with simple tron smartcontract with front end but i cant!
Here is problem:

```
PS D:\trontest> node index.js
(node:13816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: contract is not a function
    at f (D:\trontest\index.js:45:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Index.js

```
const TronGrid = require("trongrid");
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io'
});


const contractAddress = "TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ";
async function f() {
    let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contractAddress);
    const result = await contract().f().call();
    console.log(result);
}
f();
```

constract has two methods f() and g() thet return string, but i cant call it

package.json

```
{
  "name": "trontest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "trongrid": "^1.2.6",
    "tronweb": "^3.2.6"
  }
}
```

**UPD1**
Put some changings

```
const TronGrid = require("trongrid");
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io',
    headers: { "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": '*****-e677-4f4c-a9cf-2156aa5e8453' },
    privateKey: 'c4f27f7b052350703bcf*****6ecddfdd612b21c891'
});

async function f() {
    let instance = await tronWeb.contract("TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ");
    let result = await instance().f().call();
    console.log(result);
}
f();
```

```
D:\trontest>node index.js
(node:1360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.forEach is not a function
    at e.value (D:\trontest\node_modules\tronweb\dist\TronWeb.node.js:1:110856)
    at new e (D:\trontest\node_modules\tronweb\dist\TronWeb.node.js:1:108814)
    at s.value (D:\trontest\node_modules\tronweb\dist\TronWeb.node.js:1:147871)
    at f (D:\trontest\index.js:44:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\trontest\index.js:48:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

And now i see that problem is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound simply but for me this day was hard. What i just didn't do) Here is code that works:

```
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io',
    headers: { "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": '6ad9cb75-****-4f4c-a9cf-2156aa5e8453' },
    privateKey: 'c4f27f7b0*********67d3714405141cdf61b6ecddfdd612b21c891'
});

async function f() {
    let instance = await tronWeb.contract().at('TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ');
    let result = await instance['g']().call();
    console.log(result);
}
f();
```

See how correct need to type method

```
Before:
 let instance = await tronWeb.contract("TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ");
 let result = await instance().f().call(); - WRONG
After:
  let instance = await tronWeb.contract().at('TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ');
  let result = await instance['f']().call(); - RIGHT!
Or:
  let instance = await tronWeb.contract().at('TNSRwKB4YpLQTbmG9tST9zAqXXssho5hgZ');
  let result = await instance.f().call(); - RIGHT!
```

`' instead of "`, to call method `['name of method']().call();` and `instance` without `()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

instance = await tronWeb.contract().at(trc20ContractAddress)